# SQL join on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to write an `SQL` query that will return landlord information, property information and lead tenant information for a given deposit. However, my query seems to return a row, possibly for each tenant related to that deposit instead of the lead tenant and I'm wondering where I am going wrong.

The SQL code is below.

```
SELECT
IIF.ImportFileid,
Deposit.CertificateNumber AS DPCNumber,
Member.FirstNames AS LandlordFirstName, Member.LastNames AS LandlordLastNames, 
Propertys.FullAddress, 
Tenant.FirstNames AS LeadTenantFirstName, Tenant.LastNames AS LeadTenantLastNames

FROM tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryNominatedHistory 
INNER JOIN tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory AS Tenant
ON tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryNominatedHistory.MemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryID = Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryID

INNER JOIN tblMemberPropertyDeposits AS Deposit
ON Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID = Deposit.MemberPropertyDepositID

INNER JOIN tblMemberProperties AS Propertys
ON Deposit.MemberPropertyID = Propertys.MemberPropertyID

INNER JOIN tblMembers AS Member
ON Propertys.MemberID = Member.MemberID

INNER JOIN import.CommonImportDeposits AS CID
ON Member.MemberID = CID.MemberID

INNER JOIN import.ImportFiles AS IIF
ON CID.ImportFileID = IIF.ImportFileID

WHERE IIF.ImportFileID = 1091
```

Hopefully you can see from the naming convention of the tables how they are related.

Comment: How do you identify a 'lead tenant'?

Comment: @Maess They are part of the `NominatedHistory` table

Comment: and that table contains only lead tenants or all tenants?

Comment: @Maess `TenantHistory` contains all tenants `NominatedHistory` contains only lead tenants

Comment: What's some sample data? What do the tables you're using hold, and what do you expect the results to be? It appears that `tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryNominatedHistory` and/or `tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory` have information for *all* tenants, not just the "lead tenant."

Comment: @Eric read the comment above yours.

Comment: @user1016253 - Still need sample data. The query should work as you want it to if the way you say the tables are laid out is correct and your joins are correct. I won't know until I see data. Given what you've said, NominatedHistory will *only* pull back lead tenants, which are uniquely identified by `MemberPropertyDepositTenantHistoryID`. If this were truly the case, then TenantHistory would not pull back all tenants. I would start following the rabbit hole back and build the query table by table to make sure you get the results you're expecting along the way.

Comment: @Eric I think that maybe the SP related to deposits has been creating a nominated tenant for each deposit. Thank you

Comment: @user1016253 - Fantastic, glad you found the problem! Could you post an answer to yourself and mark it as the answer for posterity's sake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever had written the stored procedure had been creating duplicate nominated tenants.
Sorry guys,.